# When is an object of prototype bean gets garbage collected when we use proxy mode for Scope Protype in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

when will a prototype bean get garbage collected if we use proxy mode for scope prototype for a class in Spring boot, is it handled by Spring?

when the object of MyClassB will get garbage collected in below example or is it leading to a memory leak?

```
 @Service
    public class MyClassA {

        @Autowired
        private MyClassB myClassB;

        public String findMydata(String input) {

            String myData = myClassB.getSomeData(input);    
            return myData;
        }
    }
```

Below is the class with scope prototype which is used by above class

```
@Service
@Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE,
       proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyClassB {

        MyPojoClassA mypojoA = null;
        MyPojoClassB mypojoB = null;     

    @Autowired
    private MyClassC myClassC;

    @Autowired
    private myClassD myClassD;

    public String getSomeData(String input) {
        String SomeData = "";

            myMethodA(input);

            // makes call to external service for data  
        SomeData = myClassC.getSomeData(mypojoA.getSomething());
        myMethodB(mypojoA.getSomeOthervalue());

        if(SomeData.isBlank()){
                // retrieve the data from database.
            SomeData = myClassD.getSomeData(mypojoB.getSomething());
        }
        return SomeData;
    }

        private void myMethodA(String input){
           // process and set values in mypojoA
        }
        private void myMethodB(String input){
           // process and set values in mypojoB
        }
}
```

The usage and assigning values to different fields of myPojoA and myPojoB is done multiple times by calling different private methods inside method getSomeData. here in code sample I have not made those calls for simplicity, but have to show that there are two instance level reference variables of two classes being used.

Comment: I always thought that in general the Java Garbage Collector is undeterministic. It will run but you never know when.

Comment: The question here is when or if the object will be eligible for garbage collection in the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an object is not referenced / used by other objects, it is eligible for GC. *([Source](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) , see the section Describing Garbage Collection)*.

In your example , though you are injecting a prototyped `MyClassB` into an singleton `MyClassA` , MyClassA will always access to the same `MyClassB` instance mainly because injection of `MyClassB` into `MyClassA` will only happen once when instantiating `MyClassA` . This behaviour is well explained in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-sing-prot-interaction) as follows:

> When you use singleton-scoped beans with dependencies on prototype
>   beans, be aware that dependencies are resolved at instantiation time.
>   Thus, if you dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into a
>   singleton-scoped bean, a new prototype bean is instantiated and then
>   dependency-injected into the singleton bean. The prototype instance is
>   the sole instance that is ever supplied to the singleton-scoped bean.
>
> However, suppose you want the singleton-scoped bean to acquire a new
>   instance of the prototype-scoped bean repeatedly at runtime. You
>   cannot dependency-inject a prototype-scoped bean into your singleton
>   bean, because that injection occurs only once, when the Spring
>   container instantiates the singleton bean and resolves and injects its
>   dependencies.

As `MyClassA` is a singleton , it always exist during the application runs. It means its dependencies (i.e `MyClassB`) will always be used by that `MyClassA` instance and they will never be eligible for GC.

If you want to create a new `MyClassB` instance whenever `MyClassA` accesses `MyClassB` , you can use one of the following technique describe [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton). Just make sure the new `MyClassB` instance will never be assigned to the fields of some singleton bean , then it will be eligible to be GC when that method exit. Something like:

```java
@Service
public class MyClassA {

        @Autowired
        private Provider<MyClassB> myClassB;

        public String findMydata(String input) {
            MyClassB classB = myClassB.get(); 
            String myData = classB.getSomeData(input);    
            return myData;
        }
}
```

*<sub>I am using technique 5 described at [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton).</sub>*

Comment: In my example code , i have actually used technique 6 from same source you used technique 5, I am using Scoped Proxy. when printing objects in logs,i can see different objects of class B for different requests.

Comment: IMPORTANT: `If an object is not referenced / used by other objects, it is eligible for GC.` That's not entirely true. `singleton beans` are never garbage collected. Once created, they're only destroyed when application context is shut down.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) your client code is responsible for deleting the beans.  I assume this is similar to `InputStream` implementation classes which needs to be closed manually (either by calling `close()` or with `try-with-resources`). The destroy method to call can be customized as follows:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "closeMyBean")
public MyBean myBean(){}
```

It is unclear to me whether this will immediately remove the bean or make it eligible for the Java Garbage collector, but since Spring beans are typically not managed by the JVM I suspect the bean will be gone when the destroy method finished executing.

Take note of the following in the documentation:

> The client code must clean up prototype-scoped objects and release expensive resources that the prototype beans hold. To get the Spring container to release resources held by prototype-scoped beans, try using a custom bean post-processor, which holds a reference to beans that need to be cleaned up.

which specifies you should release any resources held by the bean as part of the destroy method or before that.